# Resaving PFUsers with modified key/values

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to write a cloud function using the Javascript Parse SDK and I was wondering if it's possible to resave a row key for various users. So far I've gotten it to query the users I want, now I'm simply trying to reset these users 'maxAwardedPosts' back to 0. I was thinking I would have to use a for loop somehow and I assume resave each individual one?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("resetUserData", function(request, response) {

 // Cycle through User Class
 // Find all Users that have 'maxAwardedPosts' > 0
 var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
 query.greaterThan("maxAwardedPosts", 0);
 query.find({
   success: function(users) {
     // Reset these users 'maxAwardedPosts' key back to 0 somehow?
   }
 });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this for a migration, you can go with a [background job](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs):

```
Parse.Cloud.job("userMigration", function(request, status) {
  // Use master key because user objects may have ACLs that prevent from modifying
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

  // Query for users having maxAwardedPosts greater than 0
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.greaterThan("maxAwardedPosts", 0);
  query.each(function(user) {
      user.set("maxAwardedPosts", 0);
      return user.save();
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });
});
```

Or use the same code in your cloud function.

Comment: +1, this is definitely something for a background job. For Cloud Function vs. Background Job, use the bg job as the time it gets to run is way larger than a cloud function. See https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-resource and https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs